# windows not showing Ubuntu files in D drive which i installed ubuntu

Tags: windows

i installed ubuntu in D drive but it only showing installation files but it cant showing the ubuntu files that means ubuntu files of my system homefolder and desktop files etc.can you help for this issue please

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Did you use the Windows Installer (WUBI), or boot from a live DVD/USB and install? Are you looking from within Windows, or have you booted Ubuntu? Please add additional information by editing the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu uses ext4 as its Filesystem (just like Windows uses NTFS/FAT32). Windows doesn't have in-built ability to read or write on this filesystem.

You would have to use a tool like [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/). However, this isn't a perfect option. It won't allow you to write on Ubuntu's Partition. So you would only be able to read the files and copy them on your NTFS/FAT32 Partition in Windows. There is one more drawback that it sometimes fails to copy large files/folders. You must always cross-check even while copying smaller files.

However, the best way to access these files is Log into Ubuntu and copy the files which you require to your Windows Partition.